# modify existing AWS VPC using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I want to modify existing VPC by removing the black holed routetabes and update it with new route tables - the routetables i want to modify are created manually (not by the terraform).  is that possible in terraform? any sample templates i can refer? Many Thanks,
Deepak

Comment: So are you saying you have existing route tables that have been created outside of Terraform and now you want to start managing them in Terraform?

Answer (score 3):

If you have existing infrastructure in AWS and you want to manage it with Terraform, you need to use the Terraform [import](https://www.terraform.io/docs/import/) command.

First, write the Terraform code that matches the route tables you already have. For example:

```
resource "aws_route_table" "example" {
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.main.id}"
}
```

Next, look up the route table ID of the existing route table, and use the `import` command to have Terraform link the Terraform code above to that existing table:

```
terraform import aws_route_table.example rtb-12345678
```

You can also try out a tool like [Terraforming](http://terraforming.dtan4.net/) which can generate the code and import the state automatically.

Comment: thank you @Yevgeniy Brikman - i will try it soon. Got into some thing else at the moment.